# Getting exception while reading xlsx file using POI jars in java

Tags: java, jar, apache-poi, xlsx

I am unable to read `xlsx` file using java, getting `Exception` as  at the line where I am creating an object XSSFWorkbook(fis);

```
HashMap<Short, String> keyMap = new HashMap<Short, String>();
HashMap<String, String> valueMap = null;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> rowList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    String fileExtn = getFileExtension(fileName);

    Workbook xssfWorkBook ;
    HSSFWorkbook hssfWorkBook ;
    Sheet sheet=null;
    if (fileExtn.equalsIgnoreCase("xlsx"))
    {
        log.debug("Before creating WorkBook");
        xssfWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        log.debug("xssfWorkBook object created");
        sheet = xssfWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
    }else  if (fileExtn.equalsIgnoreCase("xls"))
    {
        hssfWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        sheet = (Sheet) hssfWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
    }
    Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();
    int rowCount = 0;
    while (rows.hasNext()) {
        if (rowCount == 0) {
            Row row = rows.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();
            short cellCounter = 1;
            while (cells.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cells.next();
                String cellValue = getCellValueAsString(cell);
                keyMap.put(cellCounter, cellValue);
                cellCounter++;
            }
        } else {
            valueMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Row row = rows.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();
            short cellCounter = 1;
            while (cells.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cells.next();
                String cellValue = getCellValueAsString(cell);
                valueMap.put(keyMap.get(cellCounter), cellValue);
                cellCounter++;
            }
            rowList.add(valueMap);
        }
        rowCount++;
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    log.error("FileNotFoundException" + e);
    throw new Exception("FileNotFoundException while reading Excel file, Message <" + e.getMessage() + ">");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    log.error("IOException" +e);
    throw new Exception("IOException while reading Excel file, Message <" + e.getMessage() + ">");
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new Exception("Exception while reading Excel file, Message <" + e.getMessage() + ">");
}
```

Getting below exception as stackTrace is :

> java.lang.NullPointerException at 
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getPart(OPCPackage.java:562)
>   at 
>   org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:63)
>   at  org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.(POIXMLDocument.java:58) at 
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:186)
>   at 
>   com.covad.portlet.mars.util.ExcelReader.readExcel(ExcelReader.java:72)

Comment: If you went to a mechanic and told him that your car doesn't start and that it is a Ford, would you think that is sufficient information for the mechanic to fix your car?

Comment: Hi Petter, I have checked in system logs and got to that it is NullPointerException. Below is the stack trace of it java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getPart(OPCPackage.java:562)
        at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.<init>(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:63)
        at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.<init>(POIXMLDocument.java:58)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:186)
        at com.covad.portlet.mars.util.ExcelReader.readExcel(ExcelReader.java:72)

Comment: Ok this is much more useful then the error above...(that is wrapped away)

Comment: To me it seems that the xlsx file is not a correct xlsx file, poi is not able to read it. Try with another xlsx file

Comment: This is related with no answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587479/opening-excel-ooxml-2007-xlsx-document-returns-nullpointer-exception

Comment: Basically poi can not open that xlsx file, what is your option, try with update poi library..

Comment: Be sure that you have the proper permissions to read that file as well.  Also consider the possibility that you're working with an xls and *not* an xlsx.

Comment: @Neil, if it was an xls file instead of xlsx, it should throw `org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]`

Comment: According the stack trace there is a file which seems to be xlsx (zip archive with xml files) but the initializing the POIXMLDocumentPart fails while getting the PackagePart. So I suspect the file is not generated by `Excel` but by another software which does something wrong.

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue before make sure that the file is saved as 
ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx) ,the issue may happen if you saved the file as 
Strict Open XML SpreadSheet(*.xlsx),they both have the same extension but the internal structures may vary and POI seems does not support it;to solve the issue on the file re save it again as ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx) .
I hope this may solve your issue.

Comment: You saved many hours of me trying and investigating. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the above programs needs few jars as poi-3.7.jar, poi-ooxml-3.7-20101029.jar, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7-20101029.jar, xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar and dom4j-1.6.1.jar.

Also, the input file for which I was trying had some problem. I created new blank file and copied all data which I needed and tried to read the same. It worked.

Thank you All for your time and help.